# Error: Missing required param "id" Vue-router router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using Laravel 8 with Vue 3, vue-router, vue-loader

In `router/index.js`

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import CategoryShow from '../components/category/CategoryShow'
import PostShow from '../components/post/PostShow'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/categories/:id',
        name: 'categories.show',
        component: CategoryShow,
        props: true
    },
    {
        path: '/posts/:id',
        name: 'posts.show',
        component: PostShow,
        props: true
    },
]

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

In `post/PostShow.vue`

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'categories.show', params: { id: post.category_id } }">
    {{ post.category_name }}
</router-link>
```

It shows errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
at <RouterLink to= {name: 'categories.show', params: {…}} > 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "id"
```

But when I add `v-if` to this router-link tag like this:

```
<router-link v-if="typeof post.category_id !== 'undefined'" 
             v-bind:to="{ name: 'categories.show', params: { id: post.category_id } }">
    {{ post.category_name }}
</router-link>
```

It magically works!

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

I bet it's because the data loaded in your `post` variable is coming from an asynchronous call to the server side.

When the page is showing up, `post` is not loaded yet but `vue-router` is already trying to render its `router-link`, so it causes an error, trying to use a required param that, for now, is undefined.

You could link your `router-link` to the request parameter (I guess the id is from the full url) or, like you did, display the `router-link` only when the post has been loaded (that's the effet the `v-if` has).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the content of the page did not load. I want to think that when the dom was created, for some reason the route was called, the fact is that it gave me the error: Error: Missing require param "id"

**Solution**
I vast with making the id field of my dynamic route optional, this solved my problem

```js
{
  path: 'report/:id?',
  name: 'viewReport',
  component: () => import('pages/mu/bam/ReportWindow'),
  props: true 
},
```

Answer (score -1):

- i am also face this problem.

  then i was solve this problem .

  check your Api or database here

  this id is whether you have  database or not

"movie":[
{
"id":1,**this id is whether you have  database or not**
"Title": "The Lion King",
"Year": "2019",
"Runtime": "118 min",
},
]
**and then use that**

{{ post.category_name }}

**it's work**